# TypeScript - Describing an array of variable length but with at least one specific mandatory entry

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I wonder if this is possible to do

```
type Product = {
    name: string
    rules: [
        ProductRule<'forSale', boolean>,
        ...Array<ProductRule<ProductRuleKey, any>>
    ]
}
```

where I say within the `rules` key of type `Product`, which is an array, there must be a rule called `forSale`, but there can be any number of any other keys.

Alternatively of course I just move the required one out of the array, but less elegant.

Comment: "I wonder if this is possible to do" It is, that's exactly how you do it.

Comment: I read the error message I got wrong... turns out I wasn't entering a valid `ProductRuleKey` for my test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly how you do it, as per Roberto.